# Проблемы с перевод из char в string. C++

Tags: c++, строки, char

Не получается присвоить к переменной `st` переменную типа `const char`.

Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему.

```
char s;
vector<string> str;
map<char, string> encode;

while (cin >> s)
{
    encode[s];
}

for (const auto &i : encode)
{
    cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;
}

for (auto &i : encode)
{
    string st = i.first;
    str.push_back(st);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
string st = i.first;
```

имеет место не присваивание, а создание объекта типа `std::string`  из объекта типа `const char`. Однако в классе `std::string` нет соответствующего конструктора.

Используйте вместо этого следующую запись.

```
string st( 1, i.first );
```

либо

```
std::string st { i.first };
```

либо

```
std::string st = { i.first };
```

На самом деле нет никакой необходимости в цикле объявлять локальный объект `st`. Вы можете записать проще

```
for (auto &i : encode)
{
    str.push_back( { i.first } );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте не конструировать `string`, а присваивать:

```
string st;
st = i.first;
```

Конструктора такого нет, а вот присваивание - да.

Второй вариант - конструкторы

```
string(int,const char)    т.е. string st(1,i.first);
string(const char*,int)   т.е. string st(&i.first,1);
```

Итого, выбирайте любой из трех вариантов :)